# Empty request body gives 400 error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My Spring controller method looks something like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/items/{itemname}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateItem(@PathVariable String itemname, @RequestBody byte[] data) {
    // code that saves item
}
```

This works fine *except* when a try to put a zero-length item, then I get an HTTP error: **400 Bad Request**. In this case my method is never invoked. I was expecting that the method should be invoked with the "data" parameter set to a zero-length array.

Can I make request mapping work even when Content-Length is 0?

I am using Spring framework version 4.1.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a `new byte[0]` will not send any content on the request body. If you set spring MVC logs to `TRACE` you should see a message saying `Required request body content is missing` as a root cause of your `400 Bad Request`

To support your case you should make your `@RequestBody` optional

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/items/{itemname}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateItem(@PathVariable String itemname, @RequestBody(required = false) byte[] data) {
  // code that saves item
}
```